# Do all the い-adjectives become adverbs when you add く to them?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, i-adjectives, renyōkei

Do all い-adjectives become adverbs when you add く to them?  For example:

```
新しい　=　新しく
早い　　=　早く
```

But does this work with all the い-adjectives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the conjugation rule is consistent with all the い-adjectives.

There are a few notable exceptional cases where they can also syntactically be nouns:

- 近い→近く:

  - adjectival: 近くのX - the nearby X
  - noun: Xの近く - the vicinity of X
- 多い→多く:

  - adjectival: 多くのX